# Scanner input from terminal

Tags: java

First, I couldn't find any relatable post in StackOverflow.

I'm trying to get an file name input from the terminal as follow:

```
System.out.println("Get filename");
String m = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Get my name");
String n = scanner.next();
```

But I keep getting only the first part,

`eg.:`

`*filename: File.txt*`

I only get `File.` and not the `txt`-part.

Any solution to this? I don't wanna use BufferReader. Also, I have tried `trim()` and `nextLine()` without success.

---

***Edit (also solution)***:
As I have two `next()` scanners tight to each other I found that this worked for me:

```
System.out.println("Get filename");
scanner.nextLine();
String m = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Get my name");
String n = scanner.next();
```

I don't really know why. But it works.

Comment: Try scanner.nextLine(); it should get the whole line of inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `scanner.next()` splits your text from whitespaces, so you should use `scanner.nextLine()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DemoDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scanner.nextLine()` to get whole text.